# 404 error while using socket.io in angular and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

I am using socket.io to make a MEAN app. I am sending a event through my node, the event is defined in my index.js file which is included in my app.js. I am getting a 404 error while running my angular app.

```
let  express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let server = require('http').Server(express);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   console.log('User connected');
   socket.emit('hello',{
      greeting: 'Hello agam'
   });
});
module.exports = router;
```

My angular code where i have included socket.io and calling my node server

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io-client';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-component',
  templateUrl: './home-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-component.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
    const socket = socketIo('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('hello', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    });
  }

 }
```

The error which I am getting while running the app:

```
zone.js:2935 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M4aQ8Fg 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

This is My app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();



app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = new Error('Not Found');
 err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
 res.locals.message = err.message;
 res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

 res.status(err.status || 500);
 res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Please paste your code, not images or the question will be downvoted! This also applies for the error messages....

Comment: Sorry . Just did that. had to post a detail screenshot of the error. please help

Comment: the issue seems to be in your express server... can you paste code where router is included?

Comment: Just did that. please have a look

Comment: I can't see you doing `listen()` anywhere. You are also passing in express to `.Server()` without calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

...
  // And at end of file
  http.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('started on port 3000');
  });
```